# Nodejs does not render the view, after Auth with JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, axios

The nodejs does not render my view, instead it is sending on the date of my AJAX request the HTML of the view, and I do not care what it's all about.

There is no error happening, I have already tested all the codes and for me it seems everything is correct.

**FRONTEND**

```
 axios.post('/login/authentication/', {
                username: usernameInput.value,
                password: userPasswordInput.value
            }).then(response => {
                axios.post('/home/v1/', null, { headers: { Authentication: response.data.token }}).then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }).catch(error => {});
```

**JWT**

```
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports.sign = (userId, expiresInValue) => {
    const userToken = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.SECRET, {
        expiresIn: expiresInValue // EXPIRA EM 5 MINUTO
    });

    return userToken;
}

module.exports.tokenAuthentication = (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.headers. authentication){
        res.status(401).send({ 
            authStatus: false, 
            message: "NO TOKEN PROVIDED." 
        }).end();
    } else {
        jwt.verify(req.headers. authentication, process.env.SECRET, (error, decoded) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).send({ 
                    authStatus: false,
                    message: "FAILED TO AUTHENTICATE TOKEN." 
                }).end();
            } else {
                req.body.userId       = decoded.userId;
                req.body.userToken    = req.headers. authentication;
                req.body.userTokenExp = "5 min";

                next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const jwtLibrary = require('../../librarys/others/JWT');

module.exports.redirectRouter = (res) => res.redirect('/login');
module.exports.login = (res) => res.render('login/view');

module.exports.authentication = (req, res) => {
    if(!validationResult(req).isEmpty()) {
        res.status(401).send({ 
            authStatus: false, 
            message: "WITHOUT AUTHORIZATION"
        }).end();
    } else {
        /** TEMPORÁRIO */
        if(req.body.username === "1" && req.body.password === "1"){
            const jwtToken = jwtLibrary.sign(req.body.username, 300);
            res.status(200).send({ 
                authStatus: true, 
                token: jwtToken, 
                message: "AUTHORIZED"
            }).end();
        } else {
            res.status(401).send({ 
                authStatus: false, 
                message: "WITHOUT AUTHORIZATION"
            }).end();
        }
        //
    }
}
```

**HOME ROUTER**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.route('/home/v1/')
    .get(jwtLibrary.tokenAuthentication, (req, res) => {
        app.controllers.home.controller.home(req, res);
    });
}
```

**HOME CONTROLLER**

```
const jwtLibrary = require('../../librarys/others/JWT');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.route('/home/v1/').post(jwtLibrary.tokenAuthentication, (req, res) => {
        app.controllers.home.controller.home(req, res);
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's 'home/view'

Comment: @Akram home => folder, view => EJS

Comment: so you need to do like this res.render(home/view.ejs)

Comment: How the post function is called in the frontend? Is the login a form? Did you submit a form?

Comment: @AndersonMendes 
I inserted the code of the frontend in the first part of the question, what I do is the following ... I send the form, valid, and in case everything is ok I give another post calling my "home" route that I should go and renders it.

Comment: So for the node to render the view you must submit the form without using requests via axios.post, in the case of the response of the api to be render, if the response was a send json yes it would be different using axios. The render is being sent to your axio callback and not rendered by the browser. Submit the form using the post of the form itself that the node must render to the page.